# Deep linking does not open a new app

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have two apps. From the first, I want to launch the second one by deep linking. It works but the problem is that the second one starts inside the first one. I would like to start the second one in a new instance.

The code of the first app to open the second app:

```
String uri = "deeplinkTestTom://token/123456";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);
```

The manifest of the second app:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data

                android:scheme="deeplinkTestTom" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

When I try to launch Facebook app from my first app (`String uri = "facebook://facebook.com/inbox";`), it launch facebook in a new app and not inside my first app. So I suppose that something is missig in the manifest of my second app, but I can't find what.

What should I do ?

Comment: Check this https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're talking about new `Task` instead of "new app".

Read [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

You need to use `Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` to start an `Activity` in a new `Task`.

For your case, use

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Yes I'm talking about new Task. Thanks. It works with adding this flag. But is there a way to do the same by modifying the manifest of the second app ?

Comment: I just found how to do. Add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in the manifest file for the main activity.

Comment: @TomDev Good to know I could help. :)